draw_text not working in arcade for a "GAME OVER" screen
I am working on an asteroids game for my class, and have most aspects working. However, when I tried to set up a draw_text to create a "GAME OVER" flag when the final life is lost, everything works except for the draw_text that should create it on the screen.  Everything else works, there is a short delay before it returns to the games main menu.
import random
import math
import time

import arcade
import os

from typing import cast
import arcade.gui

INITIAL_ASTEROID_COUNT = 3
SCALE = 0.5
BOUNDARY_PADDING = 300
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
SCREEN_TITLE = "Asteroid Smasher"
LEFT_BOUNDARY = -BOUNDARY_PADDING
RIGHT_BOUNDARY = WINDOW_WIDTH + BOUNDARY_PADDING
BOTTOM_BOUNDARY = -BOUNDARY_PADDING
TOP_BOUNDARY = WINDOW_HEIGHT + BOUNDARY_PADDING

MENU = "MENU"
GAME = "GAME"
HOW_TO = "HOW_TO"
GAME_OVER = "GAME_OVER"

class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    """Main application class"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize game window"""
        super().__init__(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
        self.scene = MENU
        self.background = arcade.load_texture("Resources/Background/stars.png")

        self.uimanager = arcade.gui.UIManager()
        self.uimanager.enable()

        self.v_box = arcade.gui.UIBoxLayout(space_between=20)

        button_style = {
            "font_name": ("Algerian"),
            "font_size": 25,
            "font_color": (61, 212, 45),
            "bg_color": (0, 0, 0)
        }

        start_button = arcade.gui.UIFlatButton(text="New Game", width=300, style=button_style)

        start_button.on_click = self.on_click_start

        self.uimanager.add(
            arcade.gui.UIAnchorWidget(
                anchor_x='center_x',
                anchor_y='center_y',
                child=start_button
            )
        )

        how_to_button = arcade.gui.UIFlatButton(text="How To Play", width=300, style=button_style)

        how_to_button.on_click = self.how_to_play

        self.uimanager.add(
            arcade.gui.UIAnchorWidget(
                anchor_x='center_x',
                anchor_y='center_y',
                child=how_to_button
            )
        )

        self.v_box.add(start_button)
        self.v_box.add(how_to_button)

        self.uimanager.add(
            arcade.gui.UIAnchorWidget(
                anchor_x='center_x',
                anchor_y='center_y',
                child=self.v_box
            )
        )

        self.how_to_manager = arcade.gui.UIManager()
        self.how_to_manager.enable()
        return_button_style = {
            "font_name": ("Algerian"),
            "font_size": 25,
            "font_color": (61, 212, 45),
            "bg_color": (0, 0, 0)
        }
        back_button = arcade.gui.UIFlatButton(text="Back to Menu", width=300, style=return_button_style)

        back_button.on_click = self.return_to_menu

        self.how_to_manager.add(
            arcade.gui.UIAnchorWidget(
                anchor_x='left',
                anchor_y='bottom',
                child=back_button
            )
        )

        # Set the working directory (where we expect to find files) to the same
        # directory this .py file is in. You can leave this out of your own
        # code, but it is needed to easily run the examples using "python -m"
        # as mentioned at the top of this program.
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        os.chdir(file_path)

        self.frame_count = 0

        self.game_over = False

        # Sprite lists
        self.player_sprite_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.asteroid_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.ship_life_list = arcade.SpriteList()

        # Set up the player
        self.score = 0
        self.player_sprite = None
        self.lives = 3

        # Sounds
        self.laser_sound = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/hurt5.wav")
        self.hit_sound1 = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/explosion1.wav")
        self.hit_sound2 = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/explosion2.wav")
        self.hit_sound3 = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/hit1.wav")
        self.hit_sound4 = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/hit2.wav")

    def on_draw(self):

        """Render screen"""
        self.clear()
        arcade.start_render()

        if self.scene == MENU:
            arcade.draw_lrwh_rectangle_textured(0, 0,
                                                WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                                                self.background)

            self.uimanager.draw()

        elif self.scene == GAME:

            arcade.draw_lrwh_rectangle_textured(0, 0,
                                                WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                                                self.background)

            self.asteroid_list.draw()
            self.ship_life_list.draw()
            self.bullet_list.draw()
            self.player_sprite_list.draw()

            output = f"Score: {self.score}"
            arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 70, arcade.color.WHITE, 13)

            output = f"Asteroid Count: {len(self.asteroid_list)}"
            arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 50, arcade.color.WHITE, 13)

        elif self.scene == HOW_TO:

            arcade.draw_lrwh_rectangle_textured(0, 0,
                                                WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                                                arcade.load_texture("Resources/Background/howto.png"))

            self.how_to_manager.draw()

        elif self.scene == GAME_OVER:
            text = "Game Over"
            arcade.draw_text(text, 250, 300, (61, 212, 45), 30,
                             400, 'center', "Algerian", False, False,
                             'center', 'center')

   
    def on_update(self, x):

        """Update game state"""
        self.frame_count += 1

        if not self.game_over:
            self.asteroid_list.update()
            self.bullet_list.update()
            self.player_sprite_list.update()

            for bullet in self.bullet_list:
                asteroids = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(bullet,
                                                                 self.asteroid_list)

                for asteroid in asteroids:
                    # expected AsteroidSprite, got Sprite instead
                    self.split_asteroid(cast(AsteroidSprite, asteroid))
                    asteroid.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                    bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()

                # Remove bullet if it goes off-screen
                size = max(bullet.width, bullet.height)
                if bullet.center_x < 0 - size:
                    bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                if bullet.center_x > WINDOW_WIDTH + size:
                    bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                if bullet.center_y < 0 - size:
                    bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                if bullet.center_y > WINDOW_HEIGHT + size:
                    bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()

            if not self.player_sprite.respawning:
                asteroids = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite,
                                                                 self.asteroid_list)
                if len(asteroids) > 0:
                    if self.lives > 0:
                        self.lives -= 1
                        self.player_sprite.respawn()
                        self.split_asteroid(cast(AsteroidSprite, asteroids[0]))
                        asteroids[0].remove_from_sprite_lists()
                        self.ship_life_list.pop().remove_from_sprite_lists()
                        print("Crash")
                    else:
                        self.game_over = True
        elif self.game_over:
            self.game_over_screen()

    def game_over_screen(self):

        self.scene = GAME_OVER
        time.sleep(10)
        self.scene = MENU
        self.start_new_game()

def main():
    """Main function to start game"""
    window = MyGame()
    window.start_new_game()
    arcade.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

above is some of my code, primarily the MyGame init, on_update, on_draw, and game_over_screen method. I can share the entire source code, but didn't want to put too much here unless necessary so i stuck with the methods that have been directly changed working on this. I originally had the draw_text directly in the game_over_screen method but moved it to the on_draw as i assumed that was the original issue, with no change to how it runs.
Currently, after hitting an asteroid and losing the last life, it freezes for the duration of the delay, then the main menu screen returns.  Any advice would be most welcome to get this working.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

first you could use print() to see if it executes code inside elif self.scene == GAME_OVER: and if you set self.scene = GAME_OVER. Maybe you never set it - so it can't draw text.

you have self.scene = GAME_OVER time.sleep(10) self.scene = MENU - but this is useless. when you run time.sleep() then it can't run code and it can't display text. You have to use some timer and check it inside elif self.scene == GAME_OVER and change to self.scene = MENU after 10 seconds.

Hey, I appreciate the reply! I will test that out asap.

time.sleep won't work with Arcade. You have to manage sleep yourself.
Below is the simple example of displaying screen for a few seconds and then switching to another one:
import time
import arcade


class Game(arcade.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = 'Game Screen'
        self.start = time.time()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        arcade.draw_text(self.scene, self.width/2, self.height/2, arcade.color.RED, 50, anchor_x='center')

    def on_update(self, delta_time):
        if time.time()-self.start > 5:
            self.scene = 'Game Over'


Game()
arcade.run()


